# Linkedin Api Error: Direct Sponsored Content is not allowed for this app

Tags: linkedin-api

I have an error when I try to post an article to company's Linkedin page:

**Request:**

Url:

```
POST https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{company_id}/shares?format=json
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
x-li-format: json
```

Body:

```
{  
   "visibility":{  
      "code":"dark"
   },
   "comment":"test-comment",
   "content":{  
      "title":"test-title",
      "description":"test-description",
   }
}
```

**Response:**

> Direct Sponsored Content is not allowed for this app.

Linkedin's support said that they don't know what is the problem and advised to write here:) I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"visibility": {  
    "code": "dark"
},
```

visibility must be set to "all"

```
"visibility": {  
    "code": "all"
},
```